# Should I use a android sdk on a windows java app

Tags: java, android

I need to use onedrive in a windows java application. Sadly onedrive only has an [android java sdk](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android). Would it be bad to use this I mean the SDK even has a [maven repository](https://bintray.com/onedrive/Maven/onedrive-sdk-android/1.3.1), or would I be better off revamping an old client that I built for onedrive. I have tried looking this up online but I can't really find any decisive answers, or answers at all really.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work, since the sdk very clearly depends on the android build system:

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android/blob/master/onedrivesdk/build.gradle